# What could be the best way to implement 'save' feature to form in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the form which i can submit and working fine. I want to add the feature where user can save the data and later submit.

Shall i save the data in file which user filled in the form?
Any better approach?

Comment: Check out `window.localStorage`. You could serialize your form to local storage and deserialize back into the form. Or use an object.

Comment: Will it work across all the browser?

Comment: What do you mean by _Save_ ? How long data should be saved ? Why do you want to do so ? Can used edit saved data before submitting ?

Comment: If user 'A' logs in to the site and fill the form which he can submit and on submission action foo() will be taken. Now i want to provide 'Save' functionality in which if even form is partially filled, user can save the form and can complete it later and submit. So want to save the form data in some file which resides in some path like user/Date/data.txt, so that when user login to the form the save data will be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in local storage and then send to server to store.It allows you to retain the values or data when user is not on the form